array passed into Mysql query with nodejs only returning 1 result, not all
I have a sql statement/query in nodejs that should be returning 3 results, but it is only returning the first of three. (Not all results)
const { custuuid } = req.params;


var LocIds = req.query.LocIds;
  console.log(LocIds);
// LocIds = 125,124,126
      let sql =
        "SELECT L.LocID,L.LocType,L.LocName,L.LocTitle,L.LocAddress,L.StartDate,L.EndDate,L.LocLat,L.LocLng FROM  ml_locations L WHERE L.LocID IN  (?) and L.CustUUID = ? Order By LocName ASC";
      const [rows] = await pool.query(sql, [[LocIds], custuuid]);
      console.log(rows);
      console.log("Done.");

which generates the output:
125,124,126
[
  {
    LocID: 125,
    LocType: 1,
    LocName: 'Maui',
    LocTitle: 'Maui',
    LocAddress: 'Maui, Hawaii',
    StartDate: 2024-10-06T05:00:00.000Z,
    EndDate: 2024-10-06T05:00:00.000Z,
    LocLat: 20.7983626,
    LocLng: -156.3319253
  }
]
Done.

However, it should be returning 3 results. (one for each of the location 124,125,126). When I manually run the sql in phpMyAdmin, it works as intended:
SELECT L.LocID,L.LocType,L.LocName,L.LocTitle,L.LocAddress,L.StartDate,L.EndDate,L.LocLat,L.LocLng FROM ml_locations L WHERE L.LocID IN (124,125,126) and L.CustUUID = 'XXXX' Order By LocName ASC

Thoughts?

Looks a bit like you are passing in a string instead of any array. Can you try
var LocIds = req.query.LocIds.split(',').map(id => parseInt(id, 10));
and
const [rows] = await pool.query(sql, [LocIds, custuuid]);
To check if that solves your issue

Awesome - that worked! Thank you!  So I have a better understanding of why...  Did you just map the list to a new list, ensuring that the "id" was an integer?

req.query.LocIds is apparently a string in your solution and not an array. So I applied string-splitting to make it and array and parsed the array members as int
